# UITableView style set to "Grouped", but program uses "Plain" on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xib

I have created UITableViewController based class with XIB. In XIB I have changed style to "Grouped". Unfortunately, when I build the application, the table turns out to by "Plain". What might be a problem?

I have tried "Cleaning all targets". No success.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Problem solved. As you know you have to add the view to the parent controller xib. This time setting type of the controller wasn't enough. I also had to provide xib path. That fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the simulator, and restarting the sim and xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Override this method to specify number of groups

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [Arr count];
}
```

return the number of groups here

Comment: Does not work. Table shows sections in plain style. I included the screenshot.

Comment: Try to set - 
tableview.sectionFooterHeight=10;
tableview.sectionHeaderHeight=10;

If this does not work please post your code.

Comment: try to create your table using 

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style

set style to - UITableViewStyleGrouped


http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/initWithFrame:style: